# How to implement multiply fields updating inside nested arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the nested arrays in MongoDB and trying to update **multiply** values inside third level arrays :

```
const query = {'_id': id};
const inc = {'$inc':
     {'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].balance': balance}
};
const arrayFilters = {
     arrayFilters: [
          {'thread.number': threadNumber},
          {'shift.number':shiftNumber},
          {'service.name': service},
     ]
 };
 await Vds.findOneAndUpdate(query, inc, arrayFilters);
```

In this case, I had a single field update - only `balance`, but I need update two fields, `balance` and `lastUpdate` (This is time balance update).

And I forced to write second query:

```
const query = {'_id': id};
const inc = {'$inc':
     {'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].lastUpdate': new Date()}
};
const arrayFilters = {
     arrayFilters: [
          {'thread.number': threadNumber},
          {'shift.number':shiftNumber},
          {'service.name': service},
     ]
 };
 await Vds.findOneAndUpdate(query, inc, arrayFilters);
```

How to merge this queries? Something like:

```
const inc = {'$inc': [
     {'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].balance': balance},
     {'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].lastUpdate': new Date()},
 ]};
```

I've seen in [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) but not found a similar example.

**UPDATE_1**

Schema:

```
new Schema({

    ... some data
    ,
    threads: [
        {
            number: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },

            shifts: [
                {

                    ... some data

                    number: {
                        type: Number,
                        required: true
                    },
                    services: [
                        {
                            name: {
                                type: String,
                                required: true
                            },
                            lastUpdate: {
                                type: Date,
                                default: null
                            },
                            balance: {
                                type: Number,
                                default: 0
                            }

                            ... some data

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
});
```

**UPDATE_2**

Example Object:

```
{
    "isCrash": false,
    "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c88e5",
    "user": "5b44df4b46c20409cf67dac5",
    "regDate": "2018-08-19T14:58:03.030Z",
    "threads": [
        {
            "shifts": [
                {
                    "services": [
                        {
                            "lastUpdate": null,
                            "isCrash": true,
                            "balance": 27,
                            "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8919",
                        },
                        {
                            "lastUpdate": null,
                            "isCrash": true,
                            "balance": 0,
                            "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8918",
                        },
                        {
                            "lastUpdate": null,
                            "isCrash": true,
                            "balance": 0,
                            "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8917",
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8916",
                    "number": 1
                },
                {
                    "services": [
                        {
                            "lastUpdate": null,
                            "isCrash": true,
                            "balance": 0,
                            "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8915",
                        },
                        {
                            "lastUpdate": null,
                            "isCrash": true,
                            "balance": 0,
                            "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8914",
                            "name": "VIP-IP"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastUpdate": null,
                            "isCrash": true,
                            "balance": 0,
                            "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8913",
                            "name": "IP-WEB"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c8912",
                    "number": 2
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5b79857b12f80c07168c890d",
            "number": 1
        }
    ],
    "endDate": "2019-09-18T17:22:57.373Z",
    "note": "Test notes",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the fields should be inside `$inc` operator

```
const query = { '_id': id }
const update = { '$inc': {
  'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].balance': balance,
  'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].lastUpdate': new Date()
}}
const arrayFilters = {
  arrayFilters: [
    { 'thread.number': threadNumber },
    { 'shift.number' :shiftNumber },
    { 'service.name': service },
  ]
}
await Vds.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, arrayFilters)
```

Or if you want to `$set` the `lastUpdate` field

```
const query = { '_id': id }
const update = {
  '$inc': { 'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].balance': balance },
  '$set': { 'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].lastUpdate': new Date() }
}
const arrayFilters = {
  arrayFilters: [
    { 'thread.number': threadNumber },
    { 'shift.number' :shiftNumber },
    { 'service.name': service },
  ]
}
await Vds.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, arrayFilters)
```

Comment: in the second case used `$set` I got `Updating the path 'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].balance' would create a conflict at 'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].balance'`. In first case with `$inc` I got `Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].lastUpdate: new Date(1534699306238)}` May be reason my default value for lastUpdate `null`?

Comment: what is the data type for `lastUpdate` ?

Comment: type `Date` I add Schema to question.

Comment: Maybe `Date` class, not a good choice for date container in MongoDB?

Comment: well I just checked It is working for me...  Can you post your sample collection

Comment: Yes! I got it! The problem in `$inc` this work perfect `'$set': {
                'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].balance': req.body.balance,
                'threads.$[thread].shifts.$[shift].services.$[service].lastUpdate': new Date()`